# AngularJS - How to create dynamic sidebar on base of roles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create dynamic sidebar on base of user role. It is stored in $rootScope.login but I don't know how to use it in template.js

Here is my js code and am very new to AngularJS

template.js

```
$templateCache.put('template/sidebar-left.html',
        "<div class=\"sidebar-inner c-overflow\"><div class=\"profile-menu\"><a href=\"\" toggle-submenu><div class=\"profile-pic\"><img src=\"img/profile-pics/1.jpg\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"profile-info\">Malinda Hollaway <i class=\"zmdi zmdi-caret-down\"></i></div></a><ul class=\"main-menu\"><li><a data-ui-sref=\"pages.profile.profile-about\" data-ng-click=\"mactrl.sidebarStat($event)\"><i class=\"zmdi zmdi-account\"></i> View Profile</a></li><li><a href=\"\"><i class=\"zmdi zmdi-input-antenna\"></i> Privacy Settings</a></li><li><a href=\"\"><i class=\"zmdi zmdi-settings\"></i> Settings</a></li><li><a href=\"\"><i class=\"zmdi zmdi-time-restore\"></i> Logout</a></li></ul></div><ul class=\"main-menu\"><li data-ui-sref-active=\"active\"><a data-ui-sref=\"home\" data-ng-click=\"mactrl.sidebarStat($event)\"><i class=\"zmdi zmdi-home\"></i> Dashboard</a></li><li data-ui-sref-active=\"active\"><a data-ui-sref=\"timeline\" data-ng-click=\"mactrl.sidebarStat($event)\"><i class=\"zmdi zmdi-layers\"></i>Timeline</a></li>...");
```

controller.js

```
this.loginF = function(user) {

    $http.post("data/login.php", user).then(function(userData) {

        $rootScope.login = userData.data
        if( $rootScope.login == "failed" ) {
            alert(JSON.stringify($rootScope.login))
        } else {
            window.location.assign("home.html");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a directive for this, something like:

```
app.directive("userMenu", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            user: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "template/sidebar-left.html",
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
            $scope.hasRole = function(role) {
                if (!$scope.user) {
                    return false;
                }

                // assuming the user data model looks something like this:
                // { roles: ["admin", "editor"] }
                return $scope.user.roles.indexOf(role) > -1;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your sidebar-left template something like this:

```
<div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li ng-if="hasRole('admin')">
            <a href="#">This only shows if the user has the role 'admin'</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">This always shows, no matter the role</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can include it in your html:

```
<div user-menu user="$root.login"></div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I need menu items dynamically as per user roles like admin, developer etc.

Comment: You don't show any roles/object structure in your question. You probably want to create a directive for your menu, pass in the logged in user and show stuff in the template based on the user roles

Comment: Yeah I want to show menu items on base of role as I mentioned in subject of question. But I don't know how to do it. Can you please explain bit in detail that how can I use directive for that?